# channel.type.toUpperCase is not a function (discord.js/src/client/actions/ChannelUpdate.js:15)

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, discord, discord.js

I run the discord bot and get a error (Haven't ordered the bot to do anything yet). Bot automatic crashed

Discord.js v12

I rarely get this error. Is this the module's fault or is it my program's fault? And if it's my program error, how do I fix it?

```
[2021-07-30T14:41:57.765Z] Running Bot...
[2021-07-30T14:41:59.120Z] Logged in as abcxyz#1234!
[2021-07-30T14:41:59.121Z] Online
[2021-07-30T14:41:59.121Z] ==========================================================
/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/ChannelUpdate.js:15
      if (ChannelTypes[channel.type.toUpperCase()] !== data.type) {
                                    ^

TypeError: channel.type.toUpperCase is not a function
    at ChannelUpdateAction.handle (/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/ChannelUpdate.js:15:37)
    at Object.module.exports [as CHANNEL_UPDATE] (/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/CHANNEL_UPDATE.js:6:57)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/workspace/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/workspace/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:970:20)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (/workspace/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:517:14)
    at Receiver.getData (/workspace/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:435:17)
    at Receiver.startLoop (/workspace/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:143:22)
    at Receiver._write (/workspace/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:78:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at Receiver.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
```

In the first .js file loaded, I see there is 1 code related to `channel.type` :

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.type --- 'dm') return;
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        
        if(!client.commands.has(command)) return;

        try {
            client.commands.get(command).run(client, message, args);
            
        } catch (error){ 
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
});
```

ChannelUpdate.js :

```js
'use strict';

const Action = require('./Action');
const Channel = require('../../structures/Channel');
const { ChannelTypes } = require('../../util/Constants');

class ChannelUpdateAction extends Action {
  handle(data) {
    const client = this.client;

    let channel = client.channels.cache.get(data.id);
    if (channel) {
      const old = channel._update(data);

      if (ChannelTypes[channel.type.toUpperCase()] !== data.type) {
        const newChannel = Channel.create(this.client, data, channel.guild);
        for (const [id, message] of channel.messages.cache) newChannel.messages.cache.set(id, message);
        newChannel._typing = new Map(channel._typing);
        channel = newChannel;
        this.client.channels.cache.set(channel.id, channel);
      }

      return {
        old,
        updated: channel,
      };
    }

    return {};
  }
}

module.exports = ChannelUpdateAction;
```

Comment: What is `channel.type`?  You should post some relevant code.

Comment: You should add `src/client/actions/ChannelUpdate.js` as that's where the error is coming from, although there is an error in this file too, `message.channel.type --- 'dm'`. There should be three equals sign.

Comment: That's weird, looks good to me. Have you tried to log what the value of `channel` and `channel.type` is?

Comment: I don't know the value of `channel.type`, but it sounds like it's not a string. Maybe try `channel.type.toString().toUpperCase()`?